# Python Search and Replace Line

Tags: python

So I’m having trouble finding a solution to my problem. I’m new to Python and can’t seem to find the way to make this work. What I’m trying to do is iterate through all lines in a file and match multiple, distinct rules against each line and replace the entire line with user content. I’ve tried multiple methods, but neither one does what I need.

```
print ("File to perform check on:")

fileToSearch  = input( "> " )

for line in fileinput.input(fileToSearch, inplace=True):

    if 'foo' in line :

        if 'footimestwo' in line :

            sys.__stdout__.write('Wrong Answer. Try again:\n')

            textToReplace = input("")

            print(line.replace(line, textToReplace), end='')
```

This replaces the line with user input but doesn’t keep unchanged lines; it just replaces the file with the new lines.

Another method I tried was this:

```
print ("File to perform check on:")

fileToSearch  = input( "> " )

fin = open(fileToSearch, 'r') 

fout = open("newFile.txt", 'w') 

for line in fin:

    if 'foo' in line :

        if 'rom' in line :

            print ('Wrong Answer. Try again:')

            textToReplace = input( "> ")

            fout.write(textToReplace+'\n')

        else: 

            fout.write(line)
    else:

        fout.write(line)

for line in fin:

    if 'ram' in line :

        if 'foo' in line :

            print ('Wrong Answer. Try again:')

            textToReplace = input( "> ")

            fout.write(textToReplace+'\n')

        else: 

            fout.write(line)

    else:

        fout.write(line)

fin.close()

fout.close()
```

This makes the changes in a new file and keeps the state of the rest of lines for the first statement but doesn’t execute subsequent statements. Any ideas?

Comment: sum up in 1 sentence what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to search through each line of a file, match it against multiple, distinct criteria and if it matches request the user to make a change to the line and replace the line with user input while keeping all other lines that have not changed.

Comment: I'm intending this to be used to do security checks on ACL's.

Comment: I might be being dense- but which statements is it that are not getting executed in your second code example?

Comment: the second for loop isn't being executed

Comment: In terms of a strategy, the 'Chain of Responsibility' design pattern would be a good guide for implementing this. This will get rid of most of the nested if statements. Also I would favor generating a separate file to keep things immutable and allow for parallel processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first snippet of code, you do not have an `else` condition for your `if 'footimestwo' in line:` or your `if 'foo' in line :`, and so you only output the lines you are asking your user to correct.

Regarding your second snippet of code, for a small file, you would be best off just storing the lines of the file in memory:

```
smallFile = open('path/to/a/small/file.txt')
lines = smallFile.readlines()
for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    #do things, but replace lines by doing:
    lines[i] = newStuffForLine
```

Elsewise, you need to reset the file cursor:

```
bigFile = open('path/to/a/big/file.txt')
outputIntermediate = open('path/to/a/tmp/file.txt', 'w')
for line in bigFile:
     #do first set of things, putting outputs in outputIntermediate
outputIntermediate.close()
bigFile.close()
bigFile = open('oath/to/a/tmp/file.txt')
for line in bigFile:
    #do second set of things
```

In this second example, by using the intermediate file, you prevent the problem you described in the comments on this answer of simply editing the same sets of lines.

Comment: For the second snippet of code, I tried making both changes but it kept on duplicating the same lines in the new output file with either lines = smallFile.readlines() or bigFile.seek(0). I believe that's because of the fout.write(line) in the else statements I had. I changed it to continue but that didn't work because it copied the existing lines in the old file that had been changed by user input as opposed to the new lines that it had copied to the new file.

Comment: While I still can't get the second snippet to work I added else statements to the first snippet using sys.stdout.write(line) and it seems to work how I intended. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Ah yes, I see the problem there- you are outputting the changes to a different file. I've updated my answer to correct for this problem.